# Cannot install J2

Tags: python, pip

[image]

I need to install j2 package, I have switch for all version of package and switch the python3 version but it's likely fail with error above, more than I can't find this file like the error show in cli, please help me to resolve it, thanks everybody!

Comment: please post the error message as text, not an image. That way searches can find its text, and its content will be available if the image link ever breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the format of that error message where `print` isn't a function,

```
print "Requires Python %s or later" % (required_python_version)
```

and looking at the [pypi.org page for j2](https://pypi.org/project/j2/#history), where are the last update was 2011, it is clear that this is a Python 2 package.

You will have to install Python 2 if you must use the j2 package and can't find a Python3 equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

The issue would ideally be due to the pip version and the python version that you are using.

But cannot be certain till we get more information about those 2.

But what you can try is to downgrade pip to an earlier version.

For an example: `pip install pip==21.2.0` and try again.